# Mongo reference field not instantiating when using underscore js map function,

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, mongoose, underscore.js

GridComponent model has reference id (field is componentid) to Component model

```
_.map(components,function (component){
        var foo = (new Component())._id;
        component.componentid = foo;
        var gc = new GridComponent(component);

        assert(typeof gc.componentid !== 'undefined');

    })
```

fails yet

```
_.map(components,function (component){
        var foo = (new Component())._id;
        var testComponent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component));
        testComponent['componentid'] = component._id;

        var gc = new GridComponent(testComponent);

        assert(typeof gc.componentid !== 'undefined');

    })
```

passes, Can anyone explain why

Model used with mongoose and mongodb (recent versions)

```
var GridComponentSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   quantity: Number,
   componentid: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Component'
   },
   isNumeric: Boolean,
   maxlen: Number,
   processid: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'lgProcess'
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html),

> Documents have a `toObject` method which converts the mongoose document into a plain javascript object. This method accepts a few options. Instead of applying these options on a per-document basis we may declare the options here and have it applied to all of this schemas documents by default.

Or another method [toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON)